# How to insert array into a MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my array for top 10 movies

```
$data() = Array ( [0] => Array ( [rank] => 1. [rating] => 9.2 [title] => The Shawshank Redemption [year] => 1994 [number_of_votes] => 643,339 ) [1] => Array ( [rank] => 2. [rating] => 9.2 [title] => The Godfather [year] => 1972 [number_of_votes] => 488,694 ) [2] => Array ( [rank] => 3. [rating] => 9.0 [title] => The Godfather: Part II [year] => 1974 [number_of_votes] => 301,665 ) [3] => Array ( [rank] => 4. [rating] => 8.9 [title] => The Good, the Bad and the Ugly [year] => 1966 [number_of_votes] => 202,341 ) [4] => Array ( [rank] => 5. [rating] => 8.9 [title] => Pulp Fiction [year] => 1994 [number_of_votes] => 507,363 ) [5] => Array ( [rank] => 6. [rating] => 8.9 [title] => 12 Angry Men [year] => 1957 [number_of_votes] => 154,104 ) [6] => Array ( [rank] => 7. [rating] => 8.9 [title] => Schindler's List [year] => 1993 [number_of_votes] => 337,187 ) [7] => Array ( [rank] => 8. [rating] => 8.8 [title] => One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest [year] => 1975 [number_of_votes] => 265,303 ) [8] => Array ( [rank] => 9. [rating] => 8.8 [title] => The Dark Knight [year] => 2008 [number_of_votes] => 578,207 ) [9] => Array ( [rank] => 10. [rating] => 8.8 [title] => Inception [year] => 2010 [number_of_votes] => 415,584 ) )
```

Schema

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE TopMovies (rank INT, 
                                     rating VARCHAR(3), 
                                     title VARCHAR(50), 
                                     year INT, 
                                     number_of_votes INT )");
```

This is my loop

```
foreach ($data as $movie => $rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $row => $columns) {
       $query = "INSERT INTO TopMovies (rank, rating, title, year, number_of_votes)
          VALUES ({$columns['rank']}, {$columns['rating']}, {$columns['title']},
                  {$columns['year']}, {$columns['number_of_votes']});";                             
    }
    mysql_query($query);        
}
```

This is what I get, what's wrong?

```
+------+--------+-------+------+-----------------+
| rank | rating | title | year | number_of_votes |
+------+--------+-------+------+-----------------+
|    6 | 6      | 6     |    6 |               6 |
|    4 | 4      | 4     |    4 |               4 |
|    3 | 3      | 3     |    3 |               3 |
|    2 | 2      | 2     |    2 |               2 |
|    5 | 5      | 5     |    5 |               5 |
|    1 | 1      | 1     |    1 |               1 |
|    3 | 3      | 3     |    3 |               3 |
|    2 | 2      | 2     |    2 |               2 |
|    5 | 5      | 5     |    5 |               5 |
|    4 | 4      | 4     |    4 |               4 |
+------+--------+-------+------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Same thing happen when you remove the single quotes around the key names?

Comment: @Alex. Why would you do that?

Comment: @GolezTrol: Because the keys are already strings. Just throwing out suggestions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that array of data, I believe this is the loop you need:

```
foreach ($data as $movie) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO TopMovies (rank, rating, title, year, number_of_votes)
      VALUES ({$movie['rank']}, '{$movie['rating']}', '{$movie['title']}',
              {$movie['year']}, {$movie['number_of_votes']});";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Also take care to mysql_real_escape_string the data that are strings and may be input by users.

Comment: Getting an empty set with yours, thoughts?

Comment: Try to var_dump($movie) in that loop to see what it looks like and comment mysql_query() for now.  Also you can echo $query to see what it looks like.  From the array you posted I thought that should work.

Comment: Hmm, both var_dump and echo $query looks good :INSERT INTO TopMovies (rank, rating, title, year, number_of_votes) VALUES (1., '9.2', 'The Shawshank Redemption ', 1994, 643,339);

Comment: The comma in the number of votes needs to be removed, it is unbalancing your column to value count.  It thinks 643 and 339 are 2 different columns.

Comment: Either just put quotes around it (mysql wont care that its a numeric column enclosed in quotes), or $movie['number_of_votes'] = str_replace(',', '', $movie['number_of_votes']);

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO TopMovies (rank, rating, title, year, number_of_votes) VALUES "
foreach ($data as $movie => $rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $row => $columns) {
       $query += "({$columns['rank']}, '{$columns['rating']}', '{$columns['title']}',
              {$columns['year']}, {$columns['number_of_votes']}),";                             
    }      
}
#remove last comma add ';'
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: $query += should probably be .= :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the mysql_query inside the loop with the queries so you execute them.
also, you have an array of records. you need only to parse once. you don't need two loops.

so

```
foreach ($data as $record) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO .... {$record['rank']}, ...";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```